# How is the return rate on index funds calculated?

Tags: index-fund, rate-of-return

For example, I was viewing this mid-cap index fund:
http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/VMGRX:US
It says the annual return is 16.41%.

How is that calculated? The index has not risen enough in price over the past year to match with that figure. Am I miscalculating something?

Is it averaged over the past 5 years?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the Total Return for the last 12 months.

There was a dividend of $0.63 on December 22, 2014, causing the price to drop about $0.63. If you reinvest that dividend at that time, that $0.63 will continue to grow till now.

Use proper tools to look at Total Return:

https://ycharts.com/mutual_funds/M:VMGRX

You would not see the gap down in December when using this tool, and the 1y Total Return on the chart clearly says ~16%